# Make only relevant file changes trigger execution in multi-project SBT build

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to set up a multi-project build like so:

```
+-- common
|   +-- build.sbt
+-- api
|   +-- build.sbt
+-- indexer
|   +-- build.sbt
+-- build.sbt
```

`build.sbt` in root looks like so:

```
lazy val common = (project in file("common"))
lazy val searchApi = (project in file("search"))
  .dependsOn(common)
lazy val indexer = (project in file("indexer"))
  .dependsOn(common)
```

As you can see, `indexer` and `api` both depend on `common` but not on each other. The problem is if I try to do a triggered execution for a task, say `compile`:

```
sbt ~api/compile
```

Then change a file in the `indexer` project, the project will still recompile even though the file changed isn't actually on its classpath - it seems that `watchSources` is always comprised of every project referenced by the root `build.sbt` and doesn't take the project that you're actually running the task on into account.

I've tried filtering `watchSources` but it's hard to do neatly because the `build.sbt` file that I put it in can only see the resources for the project that it's in... e.g. `watchSources` in `indexer/build.sbt` can only see the watched sources inside `indexer`, `build.sbt` in the root is only watching `src/main/resources` in the root directory (it can't see the `watchSources` of the sub-projects).

Does anyone have a nice way of solving this. The best I've got is putting something like this in every subproject's `build.sbt`...

```
watchSources <<= (watchSources) map { files =>
  if (Option(System.getProperty("project")).getOrElse("none").equals("indexer")) {
    files
  } else {
    Nil
  }
}
```

... then running `sbt -Dproject=indexer ~indexer/compile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~` operator watches the currently-active project for changes. Try running `project api` first:

```
> project api
> ~compile
```